# Is it possible to type-hint arguments of a non-existent class while mocking it?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, automated-tests, phpunit

I have a DI container and want to confirm that objects type-hinting class X in their constructors will receive concrete X. The codebase contains a lot of interfaces and abstract classes. So in order to test them, I need a lot to mock non-existent classes, currently with PHPUnit

```
$this->getMockBuilder(stdClass::class)
```

Or in the case of those abstracts, with Prophecy

```
$sub = $this->prophet->prophesize("subClass");

$sub->willExtend(AbstractParent::class)

->__construct(Argument::type(get_class($dependency->reveal())))

->will (function($args) {

   $this->getDependency()->willReturn($args[0]);
});
```

However, I can't continue the Prophecy call because invoking `__construct` as I would have when defining new methods on the test double simply triggers the ObjectProphecy constructor. I imagine something like this should work in PHPUnit

```
$consumer->expects($this->any())

->method('__construct')

->with($this->isType($dependencyName))

->will($this->returnArgument(0));
```

But it complains about `dependencyName` not being a string but a Token. Moreover, even if that worked, that constructor shouldn't return a value. I can see that Mockery has a `shouldReceive` which doesn't do what I think it should i.e. assert that the mock received X argument.

Am I missing something or for type-testing, the only way out is to create some sub "/src" folder inside the tests folder where such method calls with types known at compile-time are defined? I mean is there no way to create them on the fly?

Comment: _"I have a DI container and want to confirm that objects type-hinting class X in their constructors will receive concrete X"_ - isn't that how normally a container works? If the container can't do this but you need it, I would perhaps throw it away and replace it with a component that works, but I fear you've lost me with the abstraction already in the beginning. So perhaps outline the original problem first with an example? And how is not using programming against interfaces guaranteeing the contract? In a world with real objects, who needs mocks?

Comment: @hakre I can't throw it away when I'm still trying to ascertain the work I did on it performs as intended. *In a world with real objects, who needs mocks?* Are you implying once code is ready (e.g. the one for my Container), its functionality can only be determined with the aid of real classes? How can you tell thing X was called or returned type Y? `assertSame`/`assertEquals`?

Comment: Ups, maybe I got it wrong. You're writing the container implementation yourself? Or are you using a container implemented by a third party? I have to ask because my understanding was, that just a container implementation is in use and then - and only then - my previous comment would apply (and I still have the right to be wrong). If that's not the case, then please, sorry if it appeared shocking or ignorant, that was not my intention. And I'm open to the discussion, just in case you wonder.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the container myself. Apology accepted

Comment: Okay , this then is implementation specific and very little is shared. Is the container  with  constructor injection? Is it only constructor injection? In the tests, why do you want to define the mock methods? And yes, it is fine to write mock-classes by hand and have them in the test-suite, they normally have the Mock.php suffix and are named like the test, but you can create more and put them into a subdirectory, there is no hard rule (as you can imagine).

Comment: The main reason I wanted to mock them was to avoid creating real classes. That'll mean that whenever those classes are changed, I'll only update the tests, not the test and mock classes. If by *with constructor injection* you mean if it can reflect and hydrate dependencies of a given class, then yes. *Only constructor injection*? No, it does other stuff. In what cases will it be justified to create mocks and stubs?

Comment: With _constructor injection_ I mean that the container is able to provide instances based on an interface/implementation by calling `new`. Other injection can be the container is calling an interface/implementation methods and injects as a method parameter. That method is not `__construct()`, e.g. a factory method `*::fooBarBaz()` and then returns the result.

Comment: _"In what cases will it be justified to create mocks and stubs?"_ that decision is on yourself. You use them as a tool. And concerning mocks if you test your implementation, I'd say per functionality one mock suffices just you get your container under test. It's not that you need to get your container configuration under test when the container is tested you already know the configuration does work regardless which concrete classes are configured by the container.

Comment: I don't really understand your 2nd message. If you will be open to taking a look at what I've done to confirm it's in line, here's the link https://github.com/nmeri17/Tilwa/blob/master/nmeri/tilwa/tests/Unit/App/ContainerTest.php. The one test there passes successfully and performs the desired behavior

Comment: Okay, from  quick glimpse I could see constructor injection. And I would suggest to start with testing the public methods you can directly test and check if there are some that work without mocks. It seems you've picked the hardest test first (kind of) and it is now overwhelming. With the mocks, just do them how they work for you. I would start with just creating a mock by hand because it is far more direct and to get something on the run. For higher level compositions (e.g. inheritance chains), no idea if I would stick to that, but that would be later anyway.

Comment: And perhaps what you write there is also available as a library (or you can wrap one and add your additions), Auryn comes to mind: https://github.com/rdlowrey/auryn - its open source, and they have tests. Perhaps some inspiration?

Comment: I can't extend theirs cuz some of their intended goals are quite different from mine. They combine features I broke into other components, into their Container. My entire project has parts borrowed from existing libraries (ORM, queueing, request validation), not something as simple as a Container. But thanks for referring me to their code, because after having a look at their tests, I realized they use 0 mocks. Every test is conducted against real objects. However, it's a little frustrating when people do *$o->foo("Auryn\Test\DepImplementation"), instead of *use Auryn\Test\DepImplementation*

Comment: So, I can't find those class definitions. As for your other suggestion regarding testing the easier methods first, idk how possible that'll be. It clearly works for 1 or 2, but testing the other public methods will make no meaning if that rabbit hole `getClass` is not ultimately invoked in the test. Anyway, many thanks for your patience